# Как настроить sass в phpstorm с nodejs?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, npm, sass

сделал npm install -g sass, после установки показывает в модулях sass.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При настройке file watcher ide не находит sass.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке nodejs, нет папки sass.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При npm sass -v показывает версию
Как указать путь или что нужно сделать что бы он нашел?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, глобальные модули у вас устанавливаются в `~/AppData/Roaming/npm`. вообще по идее эта папка должна быть добавлена в системный `%PATH%`, и при добавлении новых модулей IDE должна их сразу видеть. По-видимому, у вас это не так. Если перезапуск IDE не поможет, попробуйте указать полный путь к скрипту, это будет `~\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd`